# How to report Data Driven in Robot Framework with different names of test cases?

Tags: robotframework

I'm learning Robot Framework and I want to run a Excel file for my data of the test case.
When I run the code, The report shows all test case names are the same.
In my Excel file, the first column is "*** Test Cases ***". I want the name of test case will be chosen from there.

I am using Eclipse with Red Editor plugin of Nokia.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           DataDriver    ${CURDIR}/data/login_data.xlsx    DataDriven
Resource          ${CURDIR}/resources/login_resources.robot

Suite Setup       Open Browser To Login Page
Suite Teardown    Close Browser
Test Setup        Open Login Page
Test Template     Invalid Login

*** Test Cases ***
Login With Invalid Data        ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}

*** Keywords ***
Invalid Login
    [Arguments]    ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}
    [Tags]    Flat
    Input Username    ${USERNAME}
    Input Pass    ${PASSWORD}
    Click Submit Button
    Create HalfTrip Menu Should Not Be Open
```

Comment: you want dynamic test case name by following your excel file right?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to report it to know which cases are wrong or not